# How to control speaker volume with Google Home?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, home-automation

I've looked up device traits in manual https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/ but I don't see any way to control speaker type devices (volume up/down/mute). But I see that it can control its own speaker volume, chromecast, and maybe some other smart speakers. Am I missing something or is it a functionality for some special cases and is not publicly available?

Answer (score 1):

There is no trait for Volume at the moment for developers to use. Even if there were, the traits would only be usable on third party devices like for smart home devices (like a smart TV).

The behavior in a Google Home is a handler specific to the client device.

Comment: Are you saying if there was such a trait I won't be able to define a device that uses it? Why? I didn't understand that part

Comment: You can use a hypothetical volume trait to control the volume of your device through smart home in your cloud. However, you could not use it to control the volume of your Google Home.

Comment: oh ok got it. I was trying to control my other speakers. I guess for now I'll just emulate it with brightness.